# What is JMeter throughput

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

My website is hosted on cloud. I am running JMeter from my office. Now I want to know if the throughput that I get in Summary Report contain network latency also.
I have this kind of API details in my log file.

`GET mywebsite/getBday 200 67`

So for all getBday requests it gives me processing time of 67ms. But my JMeter show throughput 1.20 reqs/sec and latency here is 8.5 secs (latency = Average field from Summary Report).

Can you tell me if the throughput that I get in Summary Report contain network latency also. If so, how can I exclude it?

Answer (score 1):

Response time includes network latency. It measures the time the request was made to the time the response was received.

How can jmeter know how long the request spent in transit, unless the server can respond with a time the request was received?

The only way to exclude network latency from jmeter results is to measure it at the server and send back the information in the response (or by some other method).

Most servers should have monitoring software running anyway, like carbon/graphite. You can use that to measure the true server response times, and show network latency.

As I am most testing Java stacks, I use jconsole as well on the same machine as jmeter for side by side comparison of graphs to determine real server capability.

Answer (score 1):

"Can you tell me if the throughput that I get in Summary Report contain network latency also."?

The answer is no - throughput is a measure of the completion rate of requests and the formula for calculating it does not include latency. See below.

Probably worth looking up a definition for throughput. JMeter provides its own :

"Throughput is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server. The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time)."

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html